# Global variable not updated

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I have a problem in this code.
I am trying to parse an excel file but cannot make the parent relationship.
Parent records are created successfully, child records are also created, but parent_id is always 0

```
    let parent_id = 0; // this var not updated!!!
    let workbook = new Excel.Workbook()
    workbook = await workbook.xlsx.readFile(location)
    workbook.worksheets[0].eachRow(async (row) => {
        console.log(parent_id) // each time 0,0,0,0
        const name = row.getCell(1).value
        const obj = {
            name,
            number: row.getCell(2).value,
            parent_id: name ? null : parent_id
        }
        if(obj.number && Number(obj.number) == obj.number){
            const node = await LeadNode.create(obj)
            if(name){
                parent_id = node.id
                console.log(parent_id) // work here 1,2,3,4,5
            }
        }
    });
```

[db screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSZfD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `.eachRow()` not `await`ing for your callback to finish.

If you somehow make the callback not `async`, it would work. This means that you'll have to call this `await LeadNode.create(obj)` outside the callback.

Possible solution: create an array of `obj`, then iterate over them and call the `await LeadNode(...)`. Something like:

```
let parent_id = 0; // this var not updated!!!
let workbook = new Excel.Workbook()
workbook = await workbook.xlsx.readFile(location)
const objs = [];
workbook.worksheets[0].eachRow((row) => {
    console.log(parent_id) // each time 0,0,0,0
    const name = row.getCell(1).value
    const obj = {
        name,
        number: row.getCell(2).value,
    }
    objs.push(obj);
});

for (const obj of objs){
    if(obj.number && Number(obj.number) == obj.number){
        obj.parent_id = obj.name ? null : parent_id
        const node = await LeadNode.create(obj)
        if(name){
            parent_id = node.id
            console.log(parent_id) // work here 1,2,3,4,5
        }
    }
}
```